# Onclick event problems

Tags: javascript, html, menu, onclick

I have an issue with my onclick event. I want to have a sub-menu within my page. I have 5 icons on my page. when I click on one icon, the other 4 icons disappear. when the 4 icons disappear, there will show up an couple of buttons to go to other pages.

my problem with this event is that the other buttons, don't show up. and i do not know what the problem is...

I made a video to show the problem;

https://youtu.be/F2NUj3KVIIk

my code;

```
<div id="column">
  <p id="afbeelding-spiraal">
    <img width="150" id="spiraal" src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/spiraal-correct.png">
  </p>
</div>

<div id="column">
   <p id="afbeelding-plaat">
    <img width="150" id="plaat" src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/platenwisselaar-correct.png">
   </p>
</div>

<div id="column">
  <p id="afbeelding-lucht">
    <img width="150" id="lucht" src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/lucht-1.png">
  </p>
</div>

<div id="column">
   <p id="afbeelding-skids">
    <img width="150" id="skids" src="https://www.spiralex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/skids-correct.png">
   </p>
</div>

</div>


<div id="text">

<div id="text-buis">
    <button id="zwembadwarmtewisselaar">Zwembadwarmtewisselaar</button>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var buis = document.getElementById("buis")
var spiraal = document.getElementById("spiraal")
var plaat = document.getElementById("plaat")
var lucht = document.getElementById("lucht")
var skids = document.getElementById("skids")

    buis.onclick = function(){
    if(spiraal.className ==""){
    
    spiraal.className = "hide";
    plaat.className = "hide";
    lucht.className = "hide";
    skids.className = "hide";
    zwembadwarmtewisselaar.className = "show";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a reference to `zwembadwarmtewisselaar` also.
 `var zwembadwarmtewisselaar = document.getElementById("zwembadwarmtewisselaar");`

Comment: sorry I did! but my code is to long to copy past it to stackoverflow...

Comment: var zwembadwarmtewisselaar = document.getElementById("zwembadwarmtewisselaar");

Comment: i made a better video where you can see that i already add that var, but the onclick doesn't work... here is the link to my new video (this video is much better) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7mOG5BLRi0

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. If the elements are showing up in the DOM but you can't see them on the page, try adjusting ```z-index``` of the hidden elements in the ```.css``` file (```z-index: 99; display: relative;```).